# Farewell message - 悔しさをバネに

Tags: set-phrases

On my last day my co-worker told me this. I'm not sure what バネに means. I tried looking it up but didn't get anywhere.

> ここでの悔しさをバネに、次のとこでもがんばってくださいね

Answer (score 3):

It's an omission from バネにして, and the sentence means "Make your regret you felt here into a spring and do your best in the next place as well".

Answer (score 2):

It means "driven by regret" or "driven by frustration".
バネ is a kind of metaphor.