# meaning of リスクはバネ

Tags: meaning, metaphor

Literally it means "the risk is a spring", but that doesn't really make sense.

the original context:

> もしも旅団ではない者にこの能力を使ってしまった場合！！即座にオレ自身が命を失うようプログラムされている！！
>   これは制約と誓約！！覚悟の証！！**リスクはバネ**！！制約と覚悟が大きい程念は強く働く！！

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26068/farewell-message-%e6%82%94%e3%81%97%e3%81%95%e3%82%92%e3%83%90%e3%83%8d%e3%81%ab

Comment: This usage of バネ is far more common than you appear to think and it is clearly defined in dictionaries (if you are willing to use a monolingual dictionary).  See definition #3 here: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%99%BA%E6%9D%A1-551295#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89

Answer (score 1):

If バネ is being used metaphorically to mean 行動を起こすきっかけ as mentioned by l'électeur, and きっかけ = リスク  and 行動 = 念を強化するの, then in this context, an equivalent phrase would be リスクは念を強化するのを起こす.